# index, reps, and maximum number in a list python

Tags: python, list

Given a list of integers, find maximum value, number of maximum elements and index of last maximum in it.

so I'm trying to find the index of the last maximum, and I need to use sort, which doesn't preserve the order of the list, how do I fix this error?

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
a.sort()
if a.count(max(a)) == 1:
    print(max(a), a.count(max(a)), a.index(max(a)))
else:
    print(max(a), a.count(max(a)), len(a)-1)
```

Comment: `m = max(a);  print(m, a.count(m), len(a) - a[::-1].index(m) - 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work to print out the index of the maximum value of the list:

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
if a.count(max(a)) == 1:
  print(a.index(max(a)))
else:
  ind = len(a) - 1
  while a[ind] != max(a):
    ind -= 1
  print(ind)
```

Note: We don't need to sort `a` because the `max()` function will find the maximum of the list regardless of if it is sorted or not.

If only one maximum value occurs in the list, we just use the `.count()` function as you did.

If there are multiple maximum values and we want to print out the last one that appears, we can use a while loop to iterate backwards through the list until we find one.

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you have any further questions!